# Parsec <|> choice in parser, Error throws but does not go to next parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am learning haskell with `Write yourself a scheme`.

I am currently trying to implement a `char` recognition in scheme. A char is `#\<character>` or `#\<character-name>` like `#\a` or `#\` or `#\space`.

So i wrote the following code :

```
-- .. some code ..
data LispVal = Atom String
             | List [LispVal]
             | DottedList [LispVal] LispVal
             | String String
             | Number Integer
             | Bool Bool
             | Char Char deriving Show
-- .... More code ...
parseChar :: Parser LispVal
parseChar = liftM Char (parseSingleChar <|> parseSpecialCharNotation)

parseSingleChar :: Parser Char
parseSingleChar = do string "#\\"
                     x <- letter
                     return x

parseSpecialCharNotation :: Parser Char
parseSpecialCharNotation = do string "#\\"
                              x <- (parseSpace <|> parseNewline)
                              return x

parseSpace :: Parser Char
parseSpace = do char 's'
                char 'p'
                char 'a'
                char 'c'
                char 'e'
                return ' '

parseNewline :: Parser Char
parseNewline = do char 'n'
                  char 'e'
                  char 'w'
                  char 'l'
                  char 'i'
                  char 'n'
                  char 'e'
                  return '\n'

-- .. some more code...

readExpr :: String -> String
readExpr input = case parse parseExpr "lisp" input of
                 Left err -> "Parse Error: " ++ show err
                 Right val -> "Found value: " ++ show val
```

At this moment, i did not know about the `string` parser in `Parsec`.

The problem is that i recognizes, `#\a` but `#\space` is treated as a `s`.

```
*Main> readExpr "#\\space"
"Found value: Char 's'"
```

To resolve this problem, i changed `parseChar` as

```
parseChar :: Parser LispVal
parseChar = liftM Char (parseSpecialCharNotation <|> parseSingleChar)
```

but earlier problem is solved, but now it gives me errors with normal characters as -

```
*Main> readExpr "#\\s"
"Parse Error: \"lisp\" (line 1, column 4):\nunexpected end of input\nexpecting \"p\""
```

Why is that happening ? Should not it had moved to `parseSingleChar` as `parseSpecialCharNotation` failed ?

Full code at: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ashishnegi/a44aa0079851d06421a0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:-60--124--62-) for `<|>`:

> The parser is called predictive since q is only tried when parser p didn't consume any input (i.e.. the look ahead is 1).

In your case both the parses consume `"#\\"` before failing, so the other alternative can't be evaluated. You can use `try` to ensure backtracking works as expected:

> The parser `try p` behaves like parser `p`, except that it pretends that it hasn't consumed any input when an error occurs.

Something like the next:

```
try parseSpecialCharNotation <|> parseSingleChar
```

Side note: is it better to extract `"#\\"` out of the parsers because otherwise you are doing the same work twice. Something like the next:

```
do
  string "#\\"
  try parseSpecialCharNotation <|> parseSingleChar
```

Also, you can use [`string`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Char.html#v:string) combinator instead of a series of `char` parsers.